# Как проверить целостность резервной копии? bash backup

Tags: bash, резервное-копирование

Пишу небольшую систему резервного копирования на bash.
Если вкратце, то скрипт берет по указанному пути все файлы, имеющие заданное расширение, помещает их в единый архив и сохраняет этот архив по заданному пути.
Вопрос. Как проверить целостность готовой резервной копии при помощи контрольных сумм?
Я считаю контрольные суммы с помощью md5sum. А именно: 
В самом начале считаю сумму всех нужных файлов и определяю в отдельный файл.

```
cat *.$file_extension | md5sum > check_sum.md5
```

Затем с помощью tar записываю все файлы в архив, считаю сумму архива, и с разочарованием наблюдаю что суммы не совпадают.

```
tar -cf backup.$archive_extension *.$file_extension
md5sum backup.$archive_extension > backup.md5
```

Хотя при дальнейшей распаковке архива сумма извлеченных файлов совпадет с изначальной, с которой я их записывал в архив.
Но я не думаю что такая проверка уместна, ведь я заархивировал, а потом еще и распаковал, для того чтобы убедиться что все хорошо. Также не думаю что достаточно проверить errorlevel после записи в архив, хотя эту проверку в коде я оставил.
Как можно реализовать это правильно?

Comment: На сколько помню у тар нет проверки целостности, суммы само самбой будут разные, в голову приходит только распаковка архива в пустоту и получение результата распаковки типа `tar -xf backup.$archive_extension >> /dev/null && echo "OK" || есho "FAIL"`

Comment: А с чего это вдруг контрольная сумма файлов и запакованного бинарного архива будет совпадать? *"я заархивировал, а потом еще и распаковал, для того чтобы убедиться что все хорошо"* - Это единственная возможная проверка

Comment: Кстати, если сравнивать именно текстовое содержимое то попробуйте использовать `zcat backup.$archive_extension | md5sum`

Comment: `Затем с помощью tar записываю все файлы в архив, считаю сумму архива, и с разочарованием наблюдаю что суммы не совпадают.` Перечитал несколько раз и всё равно не совсем понял. Тебя смущает, что не совпадает md5 сырых и этих же, но запакованных файлов?